# How do you write exception handlers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Say I have an exception like `ExitFailure`. How can I match against the different values of `ExitFailure` in my handler?

```
import System.Exit (ExitCode(..))
import Control.Monad.Catch as Exc

value :: Either Exc.SomeException String
value = Exc.throwM . ExitFailure $ 23

valHandler :: Exc.SomeException -> Either Exc.SomeException String
valHandler e = ??

main = print $ Exc.catch value valHandler
```

I know `valHandler e = someValue` would match against any kind of exception, but I've never seen an example, where it matches against the kind of exception.

I can't use pattern matching, because I have `SomeException` at my hands, and I can't use equality checks, because `SomeException` doesn't have an `Eq` instance?

Comment: Why did you delete your last question about this instead of editing it?

Comment: Because my question ultimately changed. I figured out one half of the problem, but this is what is really the essence of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Exception` class offers a method for this:

```
fromException :: SomeException -> Maybe e
```

You can use this to recover the exception.

```
valHandler :: Exc.SomeException -> Either Exc.SomeException String
valHandler e
  | Just (ExitFailure code) <- fromException e
  = Right ...
  | otherwise = Left e
```